# Python input() function not adapted

Tags: python, input

I would like to add to my script a function that asks the person to enter the file tu analyse.

For example, when I compute my script like `python scipt.py` I want it to asks then `Enter data file :` then the user tells it what data file and where to find it, is it clear ?

I've tried with `input()` but this function converts what we say as a string.

Does someone know how to do this ?

Comment: what's wrong in taking the input file as string? file and its path will be string which you'll user as argument for `open(file_path)`

Comment: What the problem with string? You can also look at argparse to develop a CLI application

Comment: `input` will always give you a string, which you then have to use in `open` if you want a file. You can even do `open(input('Enter data file: '))`

Comment: Yes you're right, I had an error but it was my fault as I name my 'data file' just ```file``` which is also a  built-in function name.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

use this method or refer pathlib module in python documentation

```
from pathlib import Path
str_path = input("your file path")
path = Path(str_path)
```